# Rearrange all elements conform to the standard “firstname lastname”, preserving any titles (e.g., “Rev.”, “Dr.”, etc) or middle/second names

Tags: python, regex

This is my string

s="555-1239Dr. Bernard Lander(636) 555-0113Hollingdorp, Donnatella555-6542Fitzgerald, F. Sco
tt555 8904Rev. Martin Luther King636-555-3226Snodgrass, Theodore5553642Carlamina Scarfoni"

**

```
import re
Title = r"(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\.\s*)?"
Name1 = r"[A-Z][a-z]+,?\s+"
Middle = r"(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s*)?"
Name2 = r"[A-Z][a-z]+"**

re.findall(Title + Name1 + Middle + Name2, s)

Original data

['Dr. Bernard Lander',
 'Hollingdorp, Donnatella',
 'Fitzgerald, F. Scott',
 'Rev. Martin Luther King',
 'Snodgrass, Theodore',
 'Carlamina Scarfoni']

desired
['Dr. Bernard Lander', 
'Donnatella Hollingdorp',
 'F. Fitzgerald Scott', 
'Rev. Martin Luther King', 
'Theodore Snodgrass',
 'Carlamina Scarfoni']
```

Comment: the last part of the name2, has a typo and code is failing. it worked when I changed it to +"*"

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
names_list =[]
for name in names:
    if ("," in name):
        last, first = name.split(",")
        middle = ""
        
        if ("." in first):
            middle, first2 = first.split(".")
            middle+= "."
        else:
            first2 = first

        
        names_list.append(first2 + " " + middle + " " + last)

    else:
        names_list.append(name)
        
print(names_list)
```

```
['Dr. Bernard Lander', ' Donnatella  Hollingdorp', ' Scott  F. Fitzgerald', 'Rev. Martin Luther King', ' Theodore  Snodgrass', 'Carlamina Scarfoni']
```

[image]